# De-duplication of pandas dataframe based on key and value columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

Lets say I have a dataframe with 3 column types

1. Key Columns
2. Value Columns
3. Other Columns

Objects: Only keep a value if, it has a new value for a given key.

say I generate some random data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import string
import random

N_keys = 3
N_rows = 20

key_columns = ['key1', 'key2' ]
val_columns = ['val1', 'val2',] 
oth_columns = ['oth1', 'oth2']

random.seed(42)
np.random.seed(42)

keys = [ tuple([random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(len(key_columns))])  for _ in range(N_keys)]

last_val_dict = {}
data = []
for _ in range(N_rows):
    # Pick a key
    k = random.choice(keys)
    
    if k not in  last_val_dict:
        v = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(len(val_columns))]
    else:
        if random.random() > 0.5:
            v = [random.choice(string.ascii_letters) for _ in range(len(val_columns))]
        else:
            v = last_val_dict[k]
    last_val_dict[k] = v
    
    o = [np.random.randn()  for _ in range(len(oth_columns))]
    
    data.append({col:val for col, val in zip( key_columns+val_columns+oth_columns, list(k)+v+o )})

        
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# S,I --> I f
df.loc[5, 'val1'] = 'I'
df.loc[5, 'val2'] = 'f'
```

This dataframe has 3 keys

```
>>>> keys
>>>> ('O', 'h'), ('b', 'V'), ('r', 'p')
```

and the dataframe looks like this

```
>>>> df
>>>>  
   key1 key2 val1 val2      oth1      oth2
0     O    h    i    V  0.496714 -0.138264
1     O    h    I    f  0.647689  1.523030 (*) This should stay since for (O, h) we went from (i, V) -> (I, f)
2     r    p    B    c -0.234153 -0.234137
3     O    h    I    f  1.579213  0.767435 (*) This should NOT stay since for (O, h) we went from remained at (I, f)
4     O    h    b    J -0.469474  0.542560
5     O    h    I    f -0.463418 -0.465730 (*) This should stay since we went from (b, J) -> (I, f) even thought (I, f) is seen before
6     b    V    o    C  0.241962 -1.913280
7     r    p    B    c -1.724918 -0.562288
8     O    h    k    S -1.012831  0.314247
9     b    V    o    C -0.908024 -1.412304
10    O    h    k    S  1.465649 -0.225776
11    b    V    o    C  0.067528 -1.424748
12    b    V    o    C -0.544383  0.110923
13    b    V    Z    c -1.150994  0.375698
14    r    p    B    c -0.600639 -0.291694
15    O    h    y    f -0.601707  1.852278
16    r    p    B    c -0.013497 -1.057711
17    r    p    x    K  0.822545 -1.220844
18    O    h    c    Q  0.208864 -1.959670
19    O    h    f    o -1.328186  0.196861
```

The best logic I could come up with is the following

```
df_new = pd.concat(
    [key_df[ (key_df[val_columns] != key_df[val_columns].shift(1)).all(axis=1) ] \
         for keys, key_df in df.groupby(key_columns) ]
    ,axis=0)
```

and it does seem to work. **But I'm not sure if this could be improved upon or if I'm missing something.**

```
>>>> df_new
>>>> 
   key1 key2 val1 val2      oth1      oth2
0     O    h    i    V  0.496714 -0.138264
1     O    h    I    f  0.647689  1.523030
4     O    h    b    J -0.469474  0.542560
5     O    h    I    f -0.463418 -0.465730
8     O    h    k    S -1.012831  0.314247
15    O    h    y    f -0.601707  1.852278
18    O    h    c    Q  0.208864 -1.959670
19    O    h    f    o -1.328186  0.196861
6     b    V    o    C  0.241962 -1.913280
13    b    V    Z    c -1.150994  0.375698
2     r    p    B    c -0.234153 -0.234137
17    r    p    x    K  0.822545 -1.220844
```

Comment: Would it be possible for `(O, h)` to do  `(i, V) -> (I, f) -> (i, V)`? If yes, would the second `(i, V)` be considered _new_ or not?

Comment: Yes, that would be a NEW entry. I updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that edge case, try this:

```
df.set_index(['key1', 'key2'],inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index(['val1', 'val2'], inplace=True, append=True)
df = df.loc[[True, *(df.index[:-1] != df.index[1:])]]
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

You can take advantage of pandas' indexing to sort on the keys, then add values as indexes, and then accept any row where the value changes, and, of course, the first row. Not quite a one-liner, but still pretty readable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I think it doesn't take into account a corner case where values can repeat. I have updated the question to make that more clear.

Comment: Fixed! Updates above.

Comment: A quick run through timeit suggests our solutions have about the same performance.